# webpack-scss-sass-file does not work with conditional css extract

Tags: css, webpack, sass, gulp, extracttextwebpackplugin

I am using [WEBPACKEXTRACT-PLUGIN](https://github.com/JonathanMH/webpack-scss-sass-file) to extract `scss` into `css` file.

Having trouble with conditional extract. At moment we have **OLD-SCSS** and **NEW-SCSS** so in my `app.js` file am doing like this.

```
if (somecondition) {
  require('path-to-old.scss');
} 
else {
  require('path-to-new.scss');
}
```

But the end result is coming combination of both **OLD-SCSS** and **NEW-SCSS** regardless of *condition* is *true* or *false*.

***Is there any way to make it extract conditionally.***

Answer (score -1):

What is the context of this condition?

I would recommend you to not require this in your app.js but to put those files on webpack.config.js and conditionally change between them using node_env parameters, like this:

```
NODE_ENV="old" webpack
```

And on your webpack.config.js file:

```js
const oldOrNew = process.env.NODE_ENV;

module.exports = {
    // ...
    entry: {
        css: (oldOrNew === 'old') ? 'path-to-old.scss' : 'path-to-new.scss'
    },
    // ...
}
```

Comment: context is like `AB Testing`. for `A` load `old-css` and for `B` load `new-css`.
I am not sure how to handle that in `web.config.js` file.